# There is an error Decrypting an integer is required

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have been following this tutorial to build a simple 2D game using pygame. 
I have checked multiple times my code but I still can't figure out what this error means

```
import pygame as pygame  

pygame.init() 
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption('First Game')
pygame.display.update()
```

Here I set up all commands in response to the user's imput

```
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')
char = pygame.image.load('standing.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x = 50
y = 50
width = 64
height = 64
vel = 5

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10

left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0

run = True
```

Here I defined the frames and the corresponding pictures with each movement. The problem is coming from here but I don't understand why

```
def redrawgamewindow():
    global walkCount

window.blit(bg, (0, 0))
pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 255, 255), (x, y, width, height))


if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
    walkCount = 0
if left:
    window.blit(walkLeft[walkCount // 3], (x, y))
    walkCount += 1
elif right:
    window.blit(walkRight[walkCount // 3], (x, y))
    walkCount += 1
else:
    window.blit(char, (x, y))
    walkCount = 0
pygame.display.update() 


while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
            x -= vel
            right = False
            left = True
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - (width + vel):
            x += vel
            right = True
            left = False
        else:
            right = False
            left = False
            walkCount = 0
        if not isJump:
            if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel:
                y -= vel
            if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 500 - (height + vel):
                y += vel
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                isJump = True
                right = False
                left = False
        else:
            if jumpCount >= -10:
                neg = 1
                if jumpCount < 0:
                    neg = -1
                y -= (jumpCount * abs( jumpCount))*0.5
                jumpCount -= 1
            else:
                isJump = False
                jumpCount = 10

        redrawgamewindow()
pygame.quit()
```

The error displayed is

```
/Users/Thomas.V/Documents/Documents/Perso/Coding /Python /Pycharm Projects/Pygame.py:40: DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 255, 255), (x, y, width, height))
```

Comment: That's a warning, not an error, and it doesn't say anything about decrypting.

Comment: It is a Deprecation Warning, not Decrypting, it means that you have to pass integers to pygame.draw.rect() and one of the parameters you are passing is not an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is caused because `y` is not an integral value, because of

> ```py
> y -= (jumpCount * abs( jumpCount))*0.5
> ```

Get rid of the warning by rounding `y` (see [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)):

```py
pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 255, 255), (x, round(y), width, height))
```